# How to save the output data of second order differential equation in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, export

I am beginner in Mathematica. I am trying to save the output data as a text file but I could not save !

```
m = 9.1*(10)^(-31)
q = 1.6*(10)^(-19)
Er = 14116.83261708455 
Ep = 0
Ez = 4609.405077963418 
Br = 0.2226*(10)^(-4)
Bp = 0
Bz = 0.1825*(10)^(-4)


s = NDSolve[{r''[t] - (q/m)* Er == 0, p''[t] - (q/m)* Ep == 0, z''[t] - (q/m)* Ez == 0, r[0] == 0, r'[0] == 0, p[0] == 0, p'[0] == 0, z[0] == 0.006, z'[0] == 6.9*(10)^(5)}, {r, p, z}, {t, 0, 10}]

data1 = Table[Evaluate[{r[t]} /. s], {t, 0*(10)^(-9), 10*(10)^(-9), 0.1*(10)^(-9)} ]

data2 = Table[Evaluate[{p[t]} /. s], {t, 0*(10)^(-9), 10*(10)^(-9), 0.1*(10)^(-9)} ]

data3 = Table[Evaluate[{z[t]} /. s], {t, 0*(10)^(-9), 10*(10)^(-9), 0.1*(10)^(-9)} ]

data = Table[Prepend[{data1, data2, data3}, t], {t, 0*(10)^(-9), 10*(10)^(-9), 0.1*(10)^(-9)} ] 

TableForm[data,TableHeadings -> {None, Prepend[{"r[t]", "p[t]", "z[t]"}, t]}]

Export["myfile.txt", data, "Table"]
```

Comment: It works without problems for me. Could you clarify what is the problem?

Comment: I want all the data in a text file as a column.  all the data are mixing  in the text file. I am expecting the data for "t" in first column "r[t]"  in second and so on

Comment: You have rows which looks like `{0., {{{0.}}, {{0.0000124104}}, {{0.0000496416}}, {{0.000111694}},........` I am not surprised export is confused.

Comment: Sorry! I am expecting data in a text file like https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159564/how-to-write-the-values-of-a-function-after-each-iteration-to-a-dat-file   but I don't understand what zhk did?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be most exact, store the original function values at the gridpoints (t-values) NDSolve generates.

Generating data0, data1,... with Table, you get intepolated values less exact. With "Coordinates" and "ValuesOnGrid" you get the original grid points. Do (TableForm is only for better layout)

```
TableForm@(data = Transpose@
   Join[r["Coordinates"] /. s[[1]], 
        Through[List[r, p, z]["ValuesOnGrid"]] /. s[[1]]
])
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “TableForm is only for better layout”? Is it better visual layout of the `data` to examine it? Or better to be exported into some format?

Comment: Better for visual layout. The `data` to be stored is not affected by TableForm, since it is outside the parentheses.

Comment: it is worth clarifying, imo, that it is only for better *visual* layout, then. The OP is seemingly new here, and future users may benefit from the clarification as well, even if it is obvious to those familiar with the various `*Form`s.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @CATrevillian

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got it! Now I can save all the outputs in a single text file in the multiple columns!

```
m = 9.1*(10)^(-31)
q = 1.6*(10)^(-19)
Er = 14116.83261708455 
Ep = 0
Ez = 4609.405077963418 
Br = 0.2226*(10)^(-4)
Bp = 0
Bz = 0.1825*(10)^(-4)
s = NDSolve[{r''[t] - (q/m)* Er == 0, p''[t] - (q/m)* Ep == 0, 
   z''[t] - (q/m)* Ez == 0, r[0] == 0, r'[0] == 0, p[0] == 0, 
   p'[0] == 0, z[0] == 0.006, z'[0] == 6.9*(10)^(5)}, {r, p, z}, {t, 
   0, 10}]

data0 = Table[
  Evaluate[t /. s], {t, 0*(10)^(-9), 10*(10)^(-9), 0.1*(10)^(-9)} ]

data1 = Table[
  Evaluate[{r[t]} /. s], {t, 0*(10)^(-9), 10*(10)^(-9), 
   0.1*(10)^(-9)} ]

data2 = Table[
  Evaluate[{p[t]} /. s], {t, 0*(10)^(-9), 10*(10)^(-9), 
   0.1*(10)^(-9)} ]

data3 = Table[
  Evaluate[{z[t]} /. s], {t, 0*(10)^(-9), 10*(10)^(-9), 
   0.1*(10)^(-9)} ]

data = MapThread[{#1, Sequence @@ #2, Sequence @@ #3, 
    Sequence @@ #4} &, {data0, data1, data2, data3}]
Export["withoutB.txt", Flatten /@ data, "Table"]
```

Comment: Congratulations on getting it to work as you hoped.  To give you another way of doing it, instead of MapThread with Sequence, you could do this: Transpose[Flatten[#] & /@ {data0, data1, data2, data3}]